# MySQL - Find first match or wildcard

Tags: mysql, wildcard

I have a table with mapped variables/columns, eg:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| ele  | dim1 | dim2 | dim3 |
+------+------+------+------+
| 123  | *    | *    | *    |
| 123  | DM1  | *    | *    |
| abc  | *    | DM2  | *    |
+------+------+------+------+

CREATE TABLE `test` 
(
    `ele` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    `dim1` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    `dim2` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    `dim3` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY `test_dim1_dim2_dim3_uindex` (`ele`, `dim1`,`dim2`,`dim3`)
);
```

I want to find first match against any column that could return required match from column or wildcard instead.

```
SELECT * 
FROM test 
WHERE ele = '123' (dim1 = 'DM1' OR dim1 = '*') 
  AND (dim2 = 'DM2' OR dim2 = '*') 
  AND (dim3 = 'DM3' OR dim3 = '*');
```

Happens that this returns both columns (found one and wildcard matched, of course).

Is there any way to find matched or wildcard on failed?

Comment: First you need an order member to define first and next. Then `ORDER BY order_member LIMIT1`can help.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design. Can you amend your schema?

Comment: @Strawberry yep, I can amend it. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this would be to count the number of wildcard matches for each row (taking advantage of the fact that in a numeric context MySQL treats a boolean as either 1 or 0) and then order by that number ascending, with a `LIMIT 1` to return only the row with the least number of wildcard matches e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE ele = 123 AND
      (dim1 = 'DM1' OR dim1 = '*') AND
      (dim2 = 'DM2' OR dim2 = '*') AND
      (dim3 = 'DM3' OR dim3 = '*')
ORDER BY (dim1 = '*') + (dim2 = '*') + (dim3 = '*') ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Output:

```
ele     dim1    dim2    dim3
123     DM1     *       *
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e35e8d7238fecc39068e2476f95b551e)

Comment: @fiskolin I've modified my answer based on the changes you made to your question. Is there something else you need?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer; too long for a comment...

A normalized environment might look more like this:

```
entity dim val
     1   1   *
     1   2   *
     1   3   *
     2   1   DM1
     2   2   *
     2   3   *
```

Comment: What's new on this environment? I use `DM1`, `DM2` as an example, but column actually has `UUID` values and `UNIQUE INDEX` on combinations as well. Anyway, question was edited to make it clear.

Answer (score -1):

Do it as two separate queries, that you combine with `UNION`. Give them each an ordering column, and use that to prefer the real match instead of wildcard.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS o, test.*
    FROM test
    WHERE dim1 = 'DM1' OR dim2 = 'DM2' OR dim3 = 'DM3'
    LIMIT 1
    UNION
    SELECT 2 AS o, test.*
    FROM test
    WHERE dim1 = '*' AND dim2 = '*' AND dim3 = '*'
    LIMIT 1
) AS x
ORDER BY o
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This performs a full search in 3 derived queries. Doesn't seems to be the most performant way, but thanks anyway.

Comment: You can put `LIMIT 1` in the subqueries so the final union is tiny. There should probably be some ordering in the subqueries as well, but there's nothing in your original question that suggests how to order within the two types of results.